# Got "valueForUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key error" when use NSArrayController

Tags: macos, swift, nsarraycontroller, nsstoryboard

I'm working for NSCollectionView by using Swift. When I use a NSArrayController object as content of NSCollectionView. I got follow error:

> An uncaught exception was raised
>
> [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key plugName .

I have no idea why. I create a model named NHPlug and a NSArrayController as follow, here's my code. :

```
/* Class NHAppController */
import Cocoa

class NHAppController: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var arrayController: NSArrayController?

    var plugs: NSMutableArray?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var t = NHPlug(plugID: 1, plugName: "test")
        plugs = NSMutableArray()
        arrayController?.addObject(t)
    }
}

/* Class NSPlug */
import Cocoa

class NHPlug: NSObject {

    var plugID : Int
    var plugName : String

    init(plugID: Int, plugName: String) {
        self.plugID = plugID
        self.plugName = plugName;
    }

}
```

**If anybody could help, very appreciate for that!**

And here if crash stack:

> -01-21 19:47:07.347 Notifyhub[58369:598950] An uncaught exception was raised 2015-01-21 19:47:07.347 Notifyhub[58369:598950]
>   [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key plugName . 2015-01-21
>   19:47:07.348 Notifyhub[58369:598950] (    0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff9220b64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff950966de objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff9220b1e9 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>   0x00007fff8bd6c5ed -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:]
>   + 226     4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bc89e68 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 385     5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bca28e3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] +
>   324   6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bca28af
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 272  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8975c8bf -[NSBinder
>   valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 164  8   AppKit
>   0x00007fff89760700 -[NSValueBinder
>   _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:]
>   + 302     9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8976053b -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 276     10  AppKit                              0x00007fff897603ab
>   -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43   11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bc63c73
>   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 382    12  Foundation
>   0x00007fff8bc62e48 NSKeyValueDidChange + 463  13  Foundation
>   0x00007fff8bc679ad -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
>   didChangeValueForKey:] + 118  14  AppKit
>   0x00007fff89eb5e83 -[NSCollectionView newItemForRepresentedObject:] +
>   87    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff89ebce03
>   -[NSCollectionView _getItemsToDisplay] + 1168     16  AppKit                              0x00007fff89eb5595 -[NSCollectionView setContent:] + 217    17  AppKit
>   0x00007fff89e8e965 -[NSCollectionViewBinder _updateContent] + 93  18 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff89e8e9f0
>   -[NSCollectionViewBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 84  19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bc63c73
>   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 382    20  Foundation
>   0x00007fff8bca22a6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate)
>   _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 1142    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff897533ba -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:]
>   + 206     22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8984f126 -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 54   23  AppKit
>   0x00007fff89a1dbd0 -[NSArrayController
>   _insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:objectHandler:] + 514     24  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1d82c -[NSArrayController addObject:] + 153    25 
>   Notifyhub                           0x000000010000166a
>   _TFC9Notifyhub15NHAppController12awakeFromNibfS0_FT_T_ + 362  26  Notifyhub                           0x00000001000016d2
>   _TToFC9Notifyhub15NHAppController12awakeFromNibfS0_FT_T_ + 34     27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9211983f -[NSSet
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 223    28  AppKit
>   0x00007fff89ba2ffd -[NSIBObjectData
>   nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1216  29  AppKit
>   0x00007fff89c22122 -[NSNib
>   _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 677  30  AppKit                              0x00007fff89c22236 -[NSNib
>   _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143     31  AppKit                              0x00007fff89d5f36c -[NSStoryboard
>   instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181   32  AppKit
>   0x00007fff896afef4 NSApplicationMain + 840    33  Notifyhub
>   0x00000001000011c2 top_level_code + 34    34  Notifyhub
>   0x00000001000011fa main + 42  35  libdyld.dyli

Answer (score 5):

Got the answer myself. Post here to help any poor new guy for Swift.

In Swift KVO is not default support any more, when you declare a variable must set "**dynamic**" as follow:

```
dynamic var plugID : Int
dynamic var plugName : String
```

Comment: where did you find the documentation for this